# Google Map not rendering correctly inside FancyBox, How can I correct it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, fancybox, coffeescript

I have a present need to display a Google Map, inside a FancyBox. The tutorial shows how to do this in a straight-forward manner by using a "fancybox.iframe" CSS class, But I'll need my FancyBox to display more than just the map, ie. a form below.

So far, here's my code(very simple):

HTML

```
<div id="fancybox-container"></div>
```

CSS

```
#fancybox-container {
  display: none;
  width: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and finally some CoffeeScript:

```
$ ->
  new FancyMap()

class FancyMap
  constructor: ->
    @openMap() #once fancybox is open proceed to render the map inside of it
    options =
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.191556, -75.579716)
      zoom: 14
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    @map = new google.maps.Map $('#fancybox-container')[0], options

  openMap: ->
    $('a[href=#fancybox-container]').fancybox
      maxWidth: 500
      maxHeight: 550
      fitToView: false
      autoSize: true
      closeClick: false
      openEffect: 'none'
      closeEffect: 'none'

window.FancyMap = FancyMap
```

The result of that, is almost what I want except that the rendering is messed up,

[image: fancybox+googlemaps]

If I Drag the map inside, the result is.. something like this:

[image: fancyboxdragged]

so, in conclusion, I'm certainly missing an important property or configuration, right? Can you help me solve this issue?

Infinite Thanks in advance,

Note. I have read and tried the similar Questions here, but I'm still unsuccessful. So I reduced my issue here to its simplest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps does this when it doesn't know how big its eventually going to be, for example if you assign it to the light box before opening it the map wont know what size it needs to be.

Rather than adding the map in the constructor try adding it to the callback which will fire when the box has opened.

Code example provided by "mu is too short"
http://goo.gl/t7SOm

Comment: This may be an extremely n00b question, but.. Which callback are you talking about sir? :)

Comment: I am not familiar with CoffeeScript so I can't comment specifically but most light box libraries off the ability to get notified or to do something when they have finished opening.
Fancy box has the config option onComplete to which you can assign a function which will get fired when the box has opened.

Comment: @user766388: Something like this should work: http://goo.gl/t7SOm (that's just a crazy long coffeescript.org URL that won't fit in a comment box, jsfiddle.net is currently down or I'd use that). ArthurGuy: You can paste that into your answer if you want, I don't want to steal your thunder by adding my own answer.

Comment: Hi Guys, I have tried your solutions, here's what I've got so far..
https://gist.github.com/1792561 but still doesn't work correctly.. One thing I noticed, If you change the code inside the afterOpened for an alert, you'll notice that it gets called from the ready handler, and not when the FancyBox has finished opening. Any Ideas? 
Thank very much guys!

Comment: If your using he latest version of fancy box try afterShow rather than onComplete

Comment: Pretty Awesome, It worked very well when I switched to AfterShow !
Thank you Arthur, THANK YOU ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also [trigger](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#event) the `resize` event on the [`Map`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) to get the Maps API to resize the map container.